# Click event after filling textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:12px;">
             <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div>Instantie</div>
                </div>
                <div  class="col-md-4" >
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Instantie, new { @id = "txtInstantieName", @class = "form-control tt-input", @style = "text-transform:uppercase;" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"><button type="button" id="InstantieDetailButton">...</button></div>                 
            </div>
```

I have text box txtInstantieName after its filled i want click event for InstantieDetailButton button in Jquery. Aftter removing cursor or pressing tab or enter the click event needs to be triggered. Can someone please help.

Solution Working:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtInstantieName").focusout(function () {
        $("#InstantieDetailButton").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is possible from JQuery attach event, which JQuery version you are using?

Comment: Rahul please show us the jQuery you have tried. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a coding service and you are required to have tried yourself first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use `focusout` JQuery event to perform your desire action.
This should be something like:

```
$( "#texboxId" )
  .focusout(function() {
    console.log('Focus Out Event');
  });
```

For more details please read [Jquery Focusout Event](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Comment: Its working by using focusout Thanks fot the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use focus out event of textbox and then trigger button event as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#txtInstantieName")
  .focusout(function() {
  
   $("#InstantieDetailButton").trigger('click');
  });
 
 $("#InstantieDetailButton").click(function(){
  alert("Button Click Event Fire.");
});
});
```